# Calculate the dimension of Hilbert Curve

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

Is it possible to mathematically calculate the fractional dimension of Hilbert Curve using the formula

```
D = log(N) / log(1/r)
```

where D denotes the dimension of the fractal, N denotes the number of segments created from each parent segment and r denotes the fractional length of each side compared to the parent segment.

I know that the fractional dimension of Hilbert Curve is 2. But how to prove it mathematically?

Comment: The Hilbert curve is the image of a surjection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$.  As a set, the Hilbert curve is exactly the square, and therefore two dimensional.

Comment: Didn't understand what you said. Could you please explain in detail? @XanderHenderson